# Python3: Cannot reset colors with Colorama module

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, python-3.4, colorama

ive been trying to use colorama to print a dictionary value in a color.

i want to have a user input select the value to be colored and reset the colors of the previous selection when the user picks a differnt value, ive been able to change the color based on the selection be a can figure out how to reset the previous selections.

in the code below ive recreated the basic idea, you will see in the 'else' block some of the things ive tried to reset the colors, but they did not work.

im using Python 3.4 and colorama 0.3.3

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
from msvcrt import getch

colorama.init()

a1 = 'a1 text'
a2 = 'a2 text'
a3 = 'a3 text'
a4 = 'a4 text'

aDict = {49: a1, 50: a2, 51: a3, 52: a4}

choice = 0

# while choice is not the letter 'q'
while choice != 113:

    print('select number betweem 1 and 4:\n')
    # read key
    choice = ord(getch())

    # loop through dict of text
    for k, v in aDict.items():
        # if the key is equal to the choice
        if k == choice:
            # set the color
            aDict[k] = Fore.GREEN + v + Style.RESET_ALL
        else:
            # else reset the color
            # aDict[k] = v + Style.RESET_ALL
            # aDict[k] = Fore.RESET + v
            # print(Style.RESET_ALL)
            pass

    # print the text
    for k, v in aDict.items():
        print(v)
```

any ideas?

**ANSWER**

i was able to work a solution, although i couldn't get it to work in the situation above, it works in the real situation i needed it for. It doesnt really make sense without knowing whats in the allBoards dict but the rowString is the important part.

```
        for boards in allBoards:
            for i in range(1, 4):
            for number, board in boards.items():                                
                    if number == currentBoard:  
                        # rowString += Back.WHITE + Fore.BLACK + board[i][1] +'|'+ board[i][2] +'|'+ board[i][3] + Back.RESET + Fore.RESET + ' | '                          
                        rowString += Fore.CYAN + board[i][1] +'|'+ board[i][2] +'|'+ board[i][3] + Fore.RESET + ' | '                           
                    elif number in wins['X']:
                        rowString += Fore.RED + board[i][1] +'|'+ board[i][2] +'|'+ board[i][3] + Fore.RESET + ' | '
                    elif number in wins['O']:
                        rowString += Fore.GREEN + board[i][1] +'|'+ board[i][2] +'|'+ board[i][3] + Fore.RESET + ' | '
                    else:
                        rowString += board[i][1] +'|'+ board[i][2] +'|'+ board[i][3] + ' | '        
                rowStrings.append(rowString[:-3])
                rowString = ''

        i = 1
        for string in rowStrings:
            print(string)
            if i % 3 == 0 and i != 9:
                print('---------------------')
            i += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
aDict[k] = Fore.GREEN + v + Style.RESET_ALL
```

According to above line, GREEN, RESET_ALL keep prepend/appended.

- `GREEN` a1 text `RESET_ALL`
- `GREEN` `GREEN` a1 text `RESET_ALL` `RESET_ALL`
- `GREEN` `GREEN` `GREEN` a1 text `RESET_ALL` `RESET_ALL` `RESET_ALL`

You need to remove the surround `GREEN`, `RESET_ALL` in `else` block.

Instead of doing that, how about doing as follow with simple `if .. else ..`:

```
while choice != 113:
    print('select number betweem 1 and 4:\n')
    choice = ord(getch())
    for k, v in aDict.items():
        if k == choice:
            print(Fore.GREEN + v + Style.RESET_ALL)
        else:
            print(v)
```

Comment: in the situation above that would work perfectly, but the situation above is only a simple recreation of the problem im having in a larger project. It involves printing values from various different dictionaries to print a game board into the console. it involves looping through dictionaries and appending the values to a larger string and then printing that string after the looping is done. So im just trying to color the values in the dictionary that the user selects, then when a user selects another, i want to reset all colors in all dictionaries and re-color the new selection (dictionary).

Comment: also, the line `aDict[k] = Fore.GREEN + v + Style.RESET_ALL` only sets the `choice` to green for each iteration of the while loop. Im trying to reset the values that do not correspond to the user input in the `else` statement. I thinks thats whats happening anyway! The best solution would be if there was something that could reset the whole terminals colors after the board is printed, so next time its totally reset. So far on the first iteration i can color the particular dictionary i need, but after that the next dictionary is colored but so is the older one, i need to reset the older one

Comment: @ThriceGood, Then you need something like this in `else` block: `if aDict[k].startswith(Fore.GREEN): aDict[k] = aDict[k][len(Fore.GREEN):-len(Fore.RESET_ALL)]`

Comment: ok cool, i take it that Fore.GREEN and Fore.RESET_ALL actually append some sort of code to the string that can be removed? ansi codes or something?

Comment: @ThriceGood, Yes, you can.

Comment: using Fore.RESET seemed to work instead of Style.RESET_ALL, i wrote my solution above.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```py
print('\033[39m')
```